# Encapsulating functions and variables in an object with object-wide variables

Tags: javascript

So, I want to create an object that can contain functions and variables and objects containing functions and variables, but I find that if there are "top-level" variables, they can't be accessed by deeper functions due to scoping rules. For example:

```
var myobj = {
    foo: "test",

    bar: function() {
        return this.foo;
    },

    baz: {
        piz: "test2",
        poz: function() {
            return this.piz + this.foo;
        }
    }
}

console.log(myobj.bar());
console.log(myobj.baz.poz());
```

The second call return "test2undefined" for obvious reasons - this.foo refers to baz.foo (which is undefined) and not myobj. How can I reference myobj to allow the variable foo to be available everywhere in this object?

Comment: The second one should not throw any errors though. FWIW, this doesn't have anything to do with scope and you can't make `this` refer to two different objects. Maybe if you explain your real-world issue, we can provide useful solutions.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I tweaked my code but forgot to update. I'm just interested in the kind of best practice approach - I have an object, which I want to have some properties that are accessible everywhere in other functions, functions within objects, and so on - I don't really have an example of an application, it's more just trying to work out how to structure my code, if that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your `poz()` to:

```
poz: function() {
  return this.piz + myobj.foo;
}
```

`this` cannot refer two objects. So I'm just using the `myobj.foo`.

You wanted to refer `myobj` when you were using this at that particular line, I suppose, so why not use the object's property?

Note that you can always refer any property by referring it by the original object's name *anywhere* in the code.

Comment: I see, because myobj exists at that time, I can refer to it inside its definition? The other solution I saw was that I can assign a variable such as `self: this;` in the object literal notation, and use self to refer to the "top level" - do you know which method is generally more acceptable?

Comment: I think my answer is more acceptable, as you can't be sure what `this` refers to.(*You can be, but only if you are an expert of js*). So just use the property by referring to the original object ;)

Comment: @njp, BTW, I don't think I'm good in js. Scopes really need some time to be understood ;)

Comment: @njp: *"The other solution I saw was that I can assign a variable such as self: this; in the object literal notation"* This doesn't work though, so you don't even have to consider it as a solution.

Comment: @FelixKling, please use @ ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can change `baz` to function and remember current context

```
var myobj = {
    foo: "test",

    bar: function() {
        return this.foo;
    },

    baz:function() {
      var me = this;   

     return {    
        piz: "test2",
        poz: function() {
            return this.piz + me.foo;
        }
     }
    }
}

console.log(myobj.baz().poz());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is normal. In your `poz` function, `this` reference of baz object. Not to myobj.

To change poz function, you shoud pass context on your function like this :

```
var myobj = {
    foo: "test",

    bar: function() {
        return this.foo;
    },

    baz: {
        piz: "test2",
        poz: function(ctx) {
            return this.piz + ctx.foo;
        }
    }
}

console.log(myobj.baz.poz(myobj));
```

it's not the great solution but, in this case, it's the easyer.

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you want to access some property inside the object, you should use **var** keyword to declare it.

I've modified a little bit your example:

```
function MyObj() {
    var foo =  "test";

    this.bar = function() {
        return foo;
    };

    this.baz = {
        piz: "test2",
        poz: function() {
            return this.piz + foo;
        }
    }
}

myobj = new MyObj();

console.log(myobj.bar());
console.log(myobj.baz.poz());
```